# how can I display the displayName from my users doc in firestore?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I can login using auth and retrieve data, and the user/uid document shows on the firestore console

{displayName : "John"}

from this path path: "appname/users/uid"

However when I use

```
<div>{auth.currentUser?.displayName}</div> or console.log(auth.currentUser?.displayName)
```

I get

```
displayName: null
```

So it appears my {auth} only displays email, uid and nothing else, even though in firestore I can see my DisplayName and photoUrl that I previously saved for this user/uid

How can I show user/uid object and not rely on the auth object for the user details?

Component:

```
const fetchData = async () => {
        const userId = auth.currentUser?.uid;
        const docRef = collection(db, "users", userId as string, "pred");
        const preds = await getDocs(docRef);
        const predList = preds.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());

        console.log(predList);

        const q = doc(db, `users/${userId}`);
        console.log(q); //doesnt' work
        console.log(auth) //only shows email, displayName is null;
    };
```

If I login with google, I can see the displayName and photo, if I login with a hotmail account I can't see those, yet on firestore I have a displayName and photoUrl saved for that user in `appName/user/uid/`

firebase-auth.ts:

```
const signInWithGoogle = async () => {
    try {
        const res = await signInWithPopup(auth, googleProvider);
        const user = res.user;
        const q = query(collection(db, "users"), where("uid", "==", user.uid));
        const docs = await getDocs(q);
        if (docs.docs.length === 0) {
            await addDoc(collection(db, "users"), {
                uid: user.uid,
                name: user.displayName,
                authProvider: "google",
                email: user.email,
            });
        }
    } catch (err: any) {
        console.error(err);
        alert(err.message);
    }
};

const logInWithEmailAndPassword = async (email: any, password: any) => {
    try {
        await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
    } catch (err: any) {
        console.error(logInWithEmailAndPassword, err);
        alert("logInWithEmailAndPassword" + err.message);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

so there is a difference for getDocs, getDoc, doc and collection.
I needed to use doc with getDoc, because I was getting a doc, not querying a collection.

```
import { collection, doc, getDoc, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";

    const q = doc(db, "users", userId as string);
            const x = await getDoc(q);
            const y = x.data();
```